# Xamarin forms expandableListView/Syncfusion/CollectionView issue to limite items

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, expandablelistview, syncfusion, collectionview

I'm trying to use any expandable list in order to limit the size of the list, for example, the list returns 30 items I want to display 3. However, I'm having the option that when they expand the list the rest of 27 items will display . and when it collapses ,

we still see 3 items as the original item size setup.
Any code snippet a
t this point
is very helpful .Thanks
[image]

I tried to limit the size in code like this

```
foreach (var cusName in CustomerNames)
            {
                if (counter == 13)
                    counter = 1;
                var contact = new Contact(cusName);
                contact.CallTime = CallTime[i];
                contact.PhoneImage = ImageSource.FromResource("ExpandableListView.Images.PhoneImage.png", assembly);
                contact.ContactImage = ImageSource.FromResource("ExpandableListView.Images.Image" + counter + ".png", assembly);
                contact.AddContact = ImageSource.FromResource("ExpandableListView.Images.AddContact.png", assembly);
                contact.NewContact = ImageSource.FromResource("ExpandableListView.Images.NewContact.png", assembly);
                contact.SendMessage = ImageSource.FromResource("ExpandableListView.Images.SendMessage.png", assembly);
                contact.BlockSpan = ImageSource.FromResource("ExpandableListView.Images.BlockSpan.png", assembly);
                contact.CallDetails = ImageSource.FromResource("ExpandableListView.Images.CallDetails.png", assembly);
                i++;
                if (ContactsInfo.Count > 2)
                {
                    ContactsInfo.RemoveAt(2);

                }
                ContactsInfo.Add(contact);
```

and in fact , it removes the rest , but now I dont know how to display the rest when the click the expand option

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by updating the [SfListView.ItemsSource](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/xamarin/Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView.html#Syncfusion_ListView_XForms_SfListView_ItemsSource) in the expander view tapped event based on Boolean property.

Please refer to the following code snippets for more reference,

```
private void TapGesture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsExpanded = !this.IsExpanded;

    if (this.IsExpanded)
    {
        ListView.ItemsSource = viewModel.ContactsInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        ListView.ItemsSource = viewModel.ContactsInfo.Take(3);
    }
}
```

Also, you can update the ListView’s height based on the items count by setting the HeightRequest as mentioned below,

```
public class ExtendedListView : SfListView
{
    VisualContainer container;
    public ExtendedListView()
    {
        container = this.GetVisualContainer();
        container.PropertyChanged += Container_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Container_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            var extent = (double)container.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().FirstOrDefault(container => container.Name == "TotalExtent").GetValue(container);
            if (e.PropertyName == "Height")
                this.HeightRequest = extent;
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Refer the sample to achieve your requirement [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ListViewXamarin-2027213522).

Comment: Hey , Thanks for posting the sample . Yours collapses right back after tapping on SHOW ALL , but mine collapses the count but the view stays . any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways to achieve this function.

A common way to achieve this is to change the `ItemsSource` of the ListView.On this condition, we can define the type of `ItemsSource` to `ObservableCollection`, for example(`VeggieViewModel` is the class of item):

```
public ObservableCollection<VeggieViewModel> veggies { get; set; }

veggies = new ObservableCollection<VeggieViewModel>();
```

You can refer to the following sample code:

#### `MyViewModel.cs`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ICommand expandCommand => new Command(expandItems);

    private void expandItems()
    {
        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "Tomato2", Type = "Fruit", Image = "tomato.png"});
        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "Romaine2", Type = "Vegetable", Image = "lettuce.png"});
        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "Zucchini2", Type = "Vegetable", Image = "zucchini.png" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<VeggieViewModel> veggies { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {

        veggies = new ObservableCollection<VeggieViewModel>();

        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "Tomato", Type = "Fruit", Image = "tomato.png" });
        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "Romaine Lettuce", Type = "Vegetable", Image = "lettuce.png" });
        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "Zucchini", Type = "Vegetable", Image = "zucchini.png" });
    }
}
```

#### MyPage.Xaml

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>


<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">

        <ListView  x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="60" ItemsSource="{Binding veggies}" BackgroundColor="Gray"   >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive" >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text = "{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                            <Label Text = "{Binding Type}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="50, 35, 200, 25"     />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalOptions="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="250.25, 0.25, 50, 50 "/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

        <Label  Text="Show all accessibility features" FontAttributes="Bold"   TextDecorations="Underline" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding expandCommand}" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in many ways, I will explain in a simple way.

In the **Contact** class add another property **bool** **IsExpanded = false**.
And make it **true** for the first 3 items and show the list items based on this property. And make "**false**" for rest of the items by default. As soon as you clicked on expanded button make all of them to "**true**" for **IsExpanded** property. Automatically, all items will be visible. Do more customization as per your requirement.
Hope this will work and suits for requirement mark it as Answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: looks interesting. I let you know how it goes